# How to handle MongoDB's ObjectId with Flask?

Tags: python, json, pymongo

I have been storing references as `ObjectId` instead of strings to make it easier for `$lookup`.

However, whenever I have to return a document from a route, I have to convert the document's id and reference ids to string first. Otherwise, I would receive an error message as follows:

```
TypeError: Object of type ObjectId is not JSON serializable
```

To make things worse, after I update a document, I have to re-convert all ids and reference ids back to `ObjectId` before storing in my MongoDB collection.

Is there a smarter way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

## Option 1: Project `_id` as string in each query

The aggregation operator `$toString` can be used in projection of non-aggregated `find` queries starting from [Mongo version 4.4](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#projection).
The downside is that this projection needs to be applied across all read queries.

```
db.find(
  {"name": "Jack"},
  { "_id": {"$toString": "$_id"}, "name": 1 }
)
```

### Option 2: Store the refs as strings

You may store the refs as strings and modify the `$lookup` to match between ObjectIDs and hex strings.

Example:
A lookup from a collection `accounts` with each document containing a string field `userId` to `users` collection matching on `_id` in `users`.

```
[
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "users",
      "as": "user",
      "let": {
        "userId": "$userId"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$eq": [
                {
                  "$toObjectId": "$$userId"
                },
                "$_id"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But I am still wondering if I can make it work with ObjectId. Storing them as strings would be my last resort.

Comment: It's a tradeoff between storage space and simpler queries. I have updated the answer to include an alternative.